# How can I get arguments containing spaces from file?

Tags: bash, argument-passing, args

If I run:

```
s.sh A B="     " C
```

**s.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

count() {
    echo $#
    echo "$1" "$2" "$3"
}

count "$@"
```

I get following output:

```
3
A B=         C
```

which is the expected one. **Good!**

---

But if I run:

```
s2.sh -f file.txt
```

**s2.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

count() {
    echo $#
    echo "$1" "$2" "$3"
}    

while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    echo -e "\nLine: $line"
    count $line
done < $2
```

**file.txt**

```
A B="       " C
```

I don't get a similar output. It is:

```
Line: A B="       " C
4
A B=" "
```

**Actual**: 4 arguments

**Expected**: 3 arguments (the same as the ones mentioned in the example with the arguments provided through the command line)

I've also tried to use the following lines in **file.txt**:

```
A B='       ' C
A B=\"       \" C
A B=        C
A B=\ \ \ \ \ \ \  C
```

and to use `count "$line"`, but I couldn't achieve the expected behavior.

How can I read those arguments from file?

Comment: You need to use `eval` if you want to process quotes in a string.

Answer (score 1):

To process quotes and other metacharacters in the input line, you need to use `eval`:

```
eval "count $line"
```